# Name of the Private Property [Binable] Generates

Tags: apache-flex, data-binding, actionscript

I have a bindable public property in my ActionScript class and I want to access the private var that is generated by the [Bindable] tag.

For example, if I declare:

```
[Bindable] public var yummyTime:String = "abcdefghij";
```

at runtime, it stores the value in a variable called `_719695190yummyTime`. Anyone know how I can predict that name?

Answer (score 1):

Even if you could predict that name; you wouldn't be able to access it at compile time because you'd get a compiler error for an undefined variable.  Why do you need to access it?

I suspect that whatever you want to do can be accomplished by expanding your public variable definition into get/set methods with a Bindable event defined.  Like this:

```
private var _yummyTime : String = 'abcdefghij'
[Bindable(event='yummyTimeChanged'] 
public function get yummyTime():String{
 return _yummyTime;
}

public function set yummyTime(value:String):void{
 _yummyTime = value;
 dispatchEvent(new Event('yummyTimeChanged'));
}
```

Then inside your component, you'll have both the private variable _yummyTime and the public variable yummyTime.

Comment: Just not to confuse things: the custom event is not strictly necessary. It'll work with a simple `[Bindable]` tag and no "manual" event dispatching too.

Comment: @RIAstar I'll accept that as true, but I never tried it.  Every class in the Flex Framework manually dispatches the change event; and I just copied that convention in my own development.  Adding an event to the Bindable metadata tag is very useful if something other than the setter should trigger binding.  This happens occasionally in the Flex Framework; such as when an item in a list is selected thus changing the selectedIndex. But, I think I'm digressing.

Comment: I agree. But I tend to only use it when I need to be certain the event is dispatched only once. Also sometimes it can come in quite handy to simply listen for PropertyChangeEvents (the default event that is dispatched when you use the Bindable tag) on an entire class rather then setting up 20 separate event listeners.

Comment: My handler listening to propertyChanged events for two properties, a and b, that affect each other. So if setting property a also changes b. I need to be able to set _b, as opposed to b. Otherwise, it will get stuck in an infinite loop.

Also, this is a metaprogramming thing, so I want to be able to generically create this process for any variable. The getter / setter behavior needs to get created at runtime, so I can't explicitly define accessors.

I know [Bindable] creates those accessory for me, but I need to be able to bypass them in certain situations.

Comment: Create an alternate method for changing b.  Pass in Boolean value that specifies whether the change event should be dispatched or not. If you call it from the b setter; set it to true; if you call it from the a setter, set it to false.  This should prevent the propertyChange event from dispatching and causing a loop.  Alternately, you could specify the same Bindable event for both A, and B, and then control in your code when it is dispatched.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
[Bindable] public var yummyTime:String;
```

is the same as writing:

```
 private var _yummyTime:String;
 [Bindable]
 public function get yummyTime():String
 {
     return _yummyTime;
 }   
 public function set yummyTime(value:String):void
 {
     _yummyTime = value;
 }
```

In the second code snipped you've just explicitly written out the getter and the setter for the private variable.

Note also, that the [Bindable] tag adds a special check in the setter function as the following:

```
    private var _yummyTime:String;
    [Bindable(event="yummyTimeChange")]
    public function get yummyTime():String
    {
        return _yummyTime;
    }

    public function set yummyTime(value:String):void
    {
        if( _yummyTime !== value)
        {
            _yummyTime = value;
            dispatchEvent(new Event("yummyTimeChange"));
        }
    }
```

If you don't want that check **if( _yummyTime !== value)** you can add a custom event name in the [Bindable] tag as in the last example I've given and just don't write out the check.

Comment: I wish there was a variable called _yummyTime, but it doesn't exist. Any attempt to access this['_yummyTime'] results in an error. this['_719695190yummyTime'] can be accessed though. I found that name in the bebugger.

Comment: There is such a variable that you can access if you write it as in the second or last example I have given. Simply adding [Bindable] will just make the compiler internally use it. If you want to use it for whatever reason, you have to write explicitly the code for that. You can see the generated code from the compiler adding a compiler argument "-keep" if you are curious what the mere result of adding such a metadata tag is.